# SQL Query to Handle Variables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the Table Called `NAMES_INFO` with the following fields

```
ID
NAME
ALTERNATIVE_NAME
PREFERED_NAME
REPORTING_NAME
ALAIS_NAME
```

Now I have a new list of `NAMES` that needs to check against the each and every fields above that has `NAMES` to check for the MATCH.  So I came up with the following SQL

```
SELECT * 
FROM NAMES_INFO 
WHERE ALTERNATIVE_NAME LIKE '%PETER%THOMAS%'
OR PREFERED_NAME LIKE  '%PETER%THOMAS%'
OR REPORTING_NAME LIKE '%PETER%THOMAS%'
OR ALAIS_NAME LIKE '%PETER%THOMAS%';
```

Which works expected. But I have 3000 Names that needs to be checked against in the Excel file. So just checking is there a way to update SQL which can handle variable and run it. something like below

```
VAR1 = '%PETER%THOMAS%'
PASS TO BELOW SQL
SELECT * FROM NAMES_INFO WHERE ALTERNATIVE_NAME LIKE 'VAR1'
OR PREFERED_NAME LIKE  'VAR1'
OR REPORTING_NAME LIKE 'VAR1'
OR ALAIS_NAME LIKE 'VAR1';
```

I can't create any objects in DB. I have to do this activity in a read only environment.

Comment: Which platform are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember in SQL you don't do loops, instead you do sets or tables.  So with a table of values to check you simply do a join.

I don't know what platform you are using but here is the example code:

```
-- Oracle
WITH names2check(C) AS
(
   SELECT '%PETER%THOMAS%' as C FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
   SELECT '%SECOND%FIDDLE%' as C FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
   SELECT '%GENERIC%ALL%' as C FROM DUAL
   -- etc
    UNION ALL
   SELECT '%LAST%McLAST%' as C FROM DUAL
)
SELECT *
FROM NAME_INFO 
JOIN names2check ON 
    ALTERNATIVE_NAME LIKE names2check.C
 OR PREFERED_NAME LIKE names2check.C
 OR REPORTING_NAME LIKE names2check.C
 OR ALAIS_NAME LIKE names2check.C;
```

or

```
-- DB2 or MS SQL
WITH names2check(C) AS
(
   VALUES
     ('%PETER%THOMAS%'),
     ('%SECOND%FIDDLE%'),
     ('%GENERIC%ALL%'),
   -- etc
     ('%LAST%McLAST%')
)
SELECT *
FROM NAME_INFO 
JOIN names2check ON 
    ALTERNATIVE_NAME LIKE names2check.C
 OR PREFERED_NAME LIKE names2check.C
 OR REPORTING_NAME LIKE names2check.C
 OR ALAIS_NAME LIKE names2check.C;
```

Comment: Am using Oracle

Comment: Am getting the following error when tried for Oracle

Comment: ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword

Comment: The DB2 / Oracle solution is **incorrect** for Oracle, specifically the CTE. Easily fixed though. Change the top to (sorry for the lack of formatting in a Comment): `with names2check(c) as ( select '%PETER%THOMAS%' from dual union all select '%SECOND%FIDDLE%' from dual union all ...   select '%LAST%McLAST%' from dual)`

Comment: @mathguy -- thanks... always expect Oracle to follow the standard.

Comment: @Hogan - I would suspend any such expectations regarding Oracle, until they at least no longer treat empty strings as NULL. (In Oracle's defense, a lot of their choices were made decades before any standards even existed.)

Comment: @mathguy - please... don 't pull any punches.  :)

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, you can simplify using UNPIVOT

```
select *
from names_info
where id in (
  select id
  from names_info 
    unpivot (any_column for source_column in (alternative_name, prefered_name, reporting_name, alais_name))
  where any_column like '%PETER%THOMAS%'
);
```

Comment: Awesome this works. But it's pulling all the rows that has PETER. For instance it's also pulling in the Name is PETER,PETER DAVID, PETER THOMAS

Comment: Persist with single pattern then. Try %PETER THOMAS%